# Member "latestAnswer" not found when compiling HistoricalPriceConsumerV3.sol on Remix

Tags: chainlink

I am trying to compile HistoricalPriceConsumerV3.sol on Remix, one of the basic contracts at https://docs.chain.link/docs/historical-price-data/, however I keep getting the following error message:

"gist-1deaf4da67a4ea3c453a683a20b123be/HistoricalPriceConsumerV3.sol:44:12: TypeError: Member "latestAnswer" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in contract AggregatorV3Interface. return priceFeed.latestAnswer(); ^--------------------^"

How do I fix this?

Comment: Could you include the code you see in that gist? I ran the code you linked to from the docs and it worked without that error.

Comment: Thanks for answering, how do I see the gist code? Sorry, I'm very new..

Comment: Could you just paste all your code you're using to get this error?